# django accessing template block through custom templatetags

Tags: django

I've started working on a django project that has couple apps that are used entirely through templatetags through other apps. Voting app, comments app..etc

Although am faced with a challenge when it comes to rendering assets for that particular templatetag (css,js).

I already have a base.html with blocks for css and js but how would I be able to access them using templatetags to append related assets. Currently am heavily relying on inclusion templates and I did a lot of research and it seems impossible to touch blocks.

any advise? even if I would change the approach of using blocks am open to any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

it seems perfectly reasonable to tell the users of your library (app) that they must include your css/js somewhere in their template. E.g. [django crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#uni-form-static-files) does this. Just give them some sample code to include in their base template